# INT_BAD_COMPARISON_WITH_NONNEGATIVE_VALUE findbugs

Tags: java, findbugs, coverity

I am getting the error in my coverity.

> Suspicious integer expression
> (FB.INT_BAD_COMPARISON_WITH_NONNEGATIVE_VALUE)
>
> 1. defect: Bad comparison of nonnegative value with 0.

**Code where the issue raised**

```
                  int [][] intarray = DB Call;
                  int noofRecord = intarray[0].length;
                    if(noofRecord < 0) {
                      //some stuf
                  }
```

How can I resolve the above error.

Comment: The length of an array can never be negative. `noofRecord < 0` is completely pointless

Comment: Okay, Thank you, I will remove this line

Comment: The number zero doesn't belong to negetative numbers. The result of length is equal or greater than zero. So it makes no sense to check on negative numbers.

Comment: @QBrute I think the first line counts the number of charaters from value of element `intarray[0]`.

Comment: @Reporter `intarray` is probably a 2D array, so `intarray[0]` is a reguilar array which has the property `length`. Other than that I can only speculate, because there's not enough information about how `intarray` is actually defined.

Comment: @QBrute I have updated the question with required info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this hint from findbugs because this analyzer detects that the condition can never be true.

Array length is guranteed by the language specification to be non-negative ([JLS 16 10.7. Array Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public final field length, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.
>
> [...]

Therefore, the code inside the `if`-block can never be executed and is effectively dead code.